# Clone, fork, vfork behaviour when followed by an exec

Tags: c, multithreading, process, fork, system-calls

I am curious about the behaviour of calling clone  from a process with most of the flags set (so that the two processes share an execution context, namely share the address space, file descriptor talbe, etc). I wasn't able to fully answer my question using the material online.

Now assuming I call execve from the cloned process. This replaces the image of the process with a completely new one, destroys attached memory segments, discards allocated memory etc, but what happens to the parent process? Given these share (for example, all the malloced memory regions), do they also get deallocated?

Does the new execved process still share an address space with the parent?

Comment: `clone` is used in Linux to implement both thread creation (`pthread_create`) and process creation (`fork`). `execve` replaces an entire process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shared objects are unmapped or unlinked but from a shared perspective.

Say you have 3 processes/threads all of them sharing memory starting at 0x1000.

One of them does an execve. Then it will do an `shm_unlink(2)` on 0x1000.
`shm_unlink(2)` will try to `unlink(2)` it.

Now for each process/thread using that memory range there is a counter. In our case the counter is set to 3 before the `execve(2)` and it will be set to 2 after it. No memory loss.

The memory will be 'destroyed', as you put it, when no process is using it anymore. When the counter is 0.

Same goes for all shared objects. For a list of what system calls are called and how they're 'destroying' the shared objects have a look at the links in the `execve(2)` [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve). Search for this phrase:

```
All process attributes are preserved during an execve(), except the following
```

Comment: I see. I wasn't clear on whether the memory was freed or simply unlinked.  Now flipping it the other way: if the execved process does a malloc and somehow communicates it to the parent process, will the parent process be able to access it by just pointing a pointer to that address (read: even if I've called execve, do they continue to share the same memory address space, like they did post clone but before execve?)?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly the answer is no. If execve(2) is executed with success you'll get a new process. Not a new thread. So there will be no shared address space.

Comment: So that this mean that there is no way to run two binaries within the same address space? (assuming they are both trusted)

Comment: Nope. You have to use some form of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) or find a library that implements the second binary's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The parent process is unaffected by the execve. It's a different process after all. Processes always must use some explicit method to communicate (files, pipes, IPC like shared memory, signals, ...). Since all of this is destroyed in a child performing an exec, there's no communication possible until explicitly set up again.

Comment: True, but if you were to just use clone you could simply communicate via a shared pointer (assuming you used clone with the CLONE_VM flag set)

Comment: But how can you do that when after the execve *there is no shared pointer*? One of us is misinterpreting what execve does...is it me?